# Python, sqlite3: prompt user for file path without having to type out entire path

Tags: python, sqlite, csv, pdf

I am very new to python but i tried making a small program which imports a CSV into a sqlite3 database and matches column values with pdf names - creating folders and filling them with said pdfs.

I'm currently using

```
real_file_path = '/'.join(__file__.split('/')[:-1])
```

to get the directory where the executable file exists and using real_file_path + "specific file name" to import my CSV and find my folder with pdfs which are in the same folder as the executable file.

See example

```
new_map_path = real_file_path + "/New_map"

real_file_path + '/Db_CSVinput/mapsCSV.csv'
```

Is there a way to prompt a user for the path for both the CSV file and the folder with pdfs, without them having type in the entire path?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pathlib` if using Python 3.4+:

```
from pathlib import Path

csv = input('Please enter a csv filename: ')  # some_file.csv
pdf = input('Please enter pdf directory: ')  # some_directory

csv_file = next(Path('.').glob(f'**/{csv}'))  # Returns generator
pdf_path = next(Path('.').glob(f'**/{pdf}'))  # Returns generator
```

Here is the documentation for the library, [pathlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html).

You can also use `pathlib.Path.resolve()`, however I've had some issues using it, which is why I use the implementation in the code provided.